# String comparison of "java" with intern() is false

Tags: java, string-comparison, string-interning

Below is my code, I don't know why two results are different

This prints `true`

```
// Building "test"
String str2 = new StringBuilder("te").append("st").toString();
System.out.println(str2.intern() == str2); // true;
```

But this prints `false`

```
// Building "java"
String str2 = new StringBuilder("ja").append("va").toString();
System.out.println(str2.intern() == str2); // false;
```

Comment: `java` is generally already interned by the JVM while `test` isn't. Hence the second call returns the object interned by the JVM not the one you created

Comment: I can reproduce this if I run the two pairs of lines independently. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Its just two independent snippets, its irrelevant that the variable is declared again.

Answer (score 4):

The `String` "java" is interned somewhere else, in code that is executed prior to your code (possibly in some JDK class). Therefore `str2.intern()` returns the already interned instance of "java", which is not `== str2`.

On the other hand, the `String` "test" wasn't interned prior to your call, so your `intern` call added it to the String pool, which means `str2.intern()` returned `str2` in that case.

Comment: Instead of java "main" would do to.